# Botman studio 2.0 don't work in Ubuntu server

Tags: php, chatbot, botman

Does anyone try on Botman studio 2.0 with Ubuntu server 16.0? I tried it for telegram chatbot but it didn't work.

I can download the botman studio and driver without any error.

When I try to use **php artisan serve**, I can see **Laravel development server started: http://127.0.0.1:8000** but accessing this local URL gives 404 error.

I also tried to follow the steps on this link-

> https://botman.io/2.0/driver-telegram

Everything is installed and configured without any error yet it does not work.

Please check the screen capture below.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jh9iC.png)

Comment: If your code is placed on a remote server instead of local environment? use the ip of the remote server instead of 127.0.0.1

Comment: `php artisan serve` is meant for quick local testing through the built-in php server.  it is not meant for production. Use Apache or nginx instead.

Comment: i have use the remote IP(public ip) instead of 127.0.0.1 . but it still not work . am i need to stop the apache2 ?

Answer (score 0):

You are editing the code by FTP.

I can guess your code is on remote server instead of local server.

And 127.0.0.1 is for local.

Try to use the IP of remote server instead of 127.0.0.1 for correct access.

Just like what you do when using FTP

```
The IP address 127.0.0.1 is a special-purpose IPv4 address called localhost or loopback address. 

All computers use this address as their own but it doesn't let them communicate with other devices like a real IP address does.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to get a public URL, that would solve your issue.